# CRM365 & KingswaySoft - How to get entityid of upserted record in case of IsNew is false (case of update entity)?

Tags: dynamics-crm, entity, upsert, kingswaysoft

I'm using KingswaySoft for CRM maintenance. I'm using CRM Destination block for upsert (update or insert) based on non id attributes and need to link this entity in different entity. 
When record is created id is returned as CrmRecordId (and IsNew is true) and linking this entity is easy. 
How do get entityid in case of IsNew is false (existeing record)? CrmRecordId is empty and I did not found the way to get the entityid.

Comment: Are you using Alternate Key upsert? In other words, what's the matching criteria setting in the destination component? And also are you using WebAPI as the connection API?

Comment: This is a strange situation. I can't think of any reason that this should be happening. We have a couple of scenarios that might not return IDs, but that would happen to both create and update. If you can reach out to us through our online contact form, our team could have a look of the situation remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use an alternate key for doing `UPSERT` operation (I believe you're doing it already), if it still happens you may need to raise a support ticket with KWS support.

> **CrmRecordId**: It will return the GUID of the record irrespective of Update or Create and IsNew will specify whether the record is newly created or updated.

[Reference](https://nishantrana.me/2018/12/02/crmrecordid-and-isnew-output-in-crm-cds-destination-component/)

Comment: Sure, I can get id in case of "alternate key" selected. But I need id in case of "manually specify". I don't know why "CRM destination" works different in these two cases.